# React i18n, how to interpolate to a string (i.e. without using <Trans> component)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have this function in my React component:

```
const fireError = (n) => {
   alert(`The value should go over ${n}% to be accepted.`);
}
```

in my translation JSON I have this:

```
{ "percentage": "The value should go over {{percentage}} to be accepted" }
```

How can I make this work? Of course I cannot use the Trans component.

Comment: use `t('percentage')`, as for how to setup react `i18n`, check documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `i18n` service directly:

```js
// import it
import i18n from "i18next";

// in your React component
const fireError = (n) => {
   alert(i18n.t('percentage', { percentage: n }));
}
```

Keep in mind that the library has to be initialized before calling this function - `i18n.init()` must have already been invoked.

Comment: thanks! this works

Comment: This works also with t('....'), no need to use i18n import, but in the translation file, you need to close the atribute with double braces {{myVariable}}